# How to hide the tab name by clicking seach in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm still new in flutter, does anyone know how to make the search in the tab card like picture below:

[image]
[image]

I try to figure it out how to solve this problem but still be like this:

[image]

Here is My code that I try to solve, I'm using the custom card, the custom dialog :

```
class TabbedCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Tab> tabs;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final bool showDeleteBtn;
  final bool showPrimaryBtn;

  const TabbedCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.tabs,
      required this.children,
      this.showDeleteBtn = false,
      this.showPrimaryBtn = true})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabbedCard> createState() => _TabbedCardState();
}

class _TabbedCardState extends State<TabbedCard> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _scrHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150;

    // String searchText = "";

    TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();

    TabController _controller =
        TabController(length: widget.tabs.length, vsync: this);

    TabBar _tabBar = new TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      labelColor: kPrimaryColor,
      unselectedLabelColor: kTextGray,
      controller: _controller,
      tabs: widget.tabs,
    );

    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: _scrHeight),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 1,
                horizontal: 1,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: -4,
                    blurRadius: 35,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 9), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          AnimSearchBar(
                            width: 400,
                            textController: textController,
                            onSuffixTap: (value) {
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          _tabBar,
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        ],
                      )),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Container(
                    height: 440,
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _controller,
                      children: widget.children,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Really appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem ^^

Comment: please add you code too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

first create `bool showSearchView = false`, then create two widget like this:

```
_tabView() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 100,
          height: 40,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 100,
          height: 40,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 100,
          height: 40,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

and

```
_searchView() {
    return TextField();
  }
```

then, use it like this:

```
Row(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showSearchView = !showSearchView;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(showSearchView ? Icons.close : Icons.search),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: showSearchView ? _searchView() : _tabView(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```